# Google Maps API - using ch1903 instead of Lat/Long

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I encountered a problem and failed to find a solution up until now:
Google´s Maps API uses Lat/Long coordinates to find a certain location.

I´m currently trying to write an app which displays a location after entering coordinates. The problem is the typ of coords I get:

Our Rescue Coordination Center only provids coords in SwissGrid(ch1903) e.g. 4416984.21 / 5392873.07.

Do you know a work-around or a solution to use these coords with the Anroid GM API.

Thanks and greetings from Germany.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert SwissGrid(ch1903) to Lat/Lang.. [This like might be useful](http://www.giangrandi.ch/soft/swissgrid/swissgrid.shtml)